# Sort highest to lowest in a file

Tags: python

I'm new with python. Recently I've encountered a problem where I am suppose to print a sorted leaderboard of a fake game.

Here's my code:

```
myfile = open('Results.txt')
title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format('Player Nickname','Matches Played','Matches Won','Matches Lost','Points')
print(title)
for line in myfile:
    item = line.split(',')
    points = int(item[2]) * 3
    if points != 0:
        result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:<20}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3].rstrip(), points)
        print(result)
```

and here's a few examples in the file

```
Leeroy,19,7,12
Jenkins,19,8,11
Tyler,19,0,19
```

I had to use .rstrip() to remove the \n escape code so the format can work properly.

Is there any really simple way of sorting the file? instead of things like lambda and just really complicated stuff?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: oh yes, my friend did teach me using lambda but it was too complicated so I was asking if there is any easier way

`scores = []
myfile = open('Results.txt')
for line in myfile:
    scores.append(line.split(','))

sortedScores  = sorted(scores,key=lambda x: x[2]*3)`

using coding that is easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sortedScores = sorted(scores,key=lambda x: x[2]*3)

You were almost there! All you needed to do is:

```
sortedScores = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: int(x[2])*3)
```

*You forgot to convert the value to an integer before multiplying it*

---

Here's one way - just add the calculated points as you read the file, then sort the result and print it:

```
data = []

for line in myfile:
    item = line.split(',')
    points = int(item[2]) * 3
    item.append(points)
    data.append(item)

# Now, sort it, the easiest way is to tell it to sort by the last item
import operator
data = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(4), reverse=True)

# or, you can write a lambda!
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[4], reverse=True)

for item in data: 
    result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:<20}'.format(*item)
    print(result)
```

Comment: it printed a whole repeated list of the same names what did I do wrong?
`data = ()
    for line in myfile:
        item = line.split(',')
        points = int(item[2]) * 3
        item.append(points)
        data.append(item)
        if points != 0:
            data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[4], reverse=True)
        for item in data:
            result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:<20}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3].rstrip(), points)
            print(result)`